# Swapping the order in an idiomatic expression

Tags: idioms, expressions, word-order

I may have sounded general in the title but my question is very specific. Recently I was writing a poem and I needed it to rhyme this way

> Some will stand to watch you go down quick
>
> But no one will follow you through thin and thick

It didn't seem right to me to change the order in the expression *"through thick and thin"*. Is what I have done acceptable? Or should I stick to the right order?

Comment: Poetry may very well have its own rules (or sometimes no rules) but if the idiom is very familiar, mixing it up can work and will still catch the eye of the reader, as your line did for me.  I knew what was meant and that you switched "thick" and "thin" to force the rhyme.  Maybe others with more knowledge or poetic talent can tell you why you should or shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Kristina: Specific *types* of poetry (such as sonnets and haikus) do indeed have "rules", but the more general rule is that you can do what you like in poetry - non-standard grammar, orthography, etc., are often described as "poetic" for that very reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, good points.  I love haikus just for the rigid rule.

Comment: @Kristina: But I bet you don't *always* count the syllables! What if you read a haiku you *really* liked, then discovered later that it actually had 16 syllables instead of 17? Would you like it any the less? But I don't have to count or look up anything to know I don't much like OP's offering - I'm sure it's summat to do with not being metrically divided into *iambs, trochees, spondees, anapests* or *dactyls*, but I don't need to know "the rules" to feel that those lines don't do it for me.

Comment: @fum, agreed - it's forced and doesn't flow. I don't know *spondees* from *spandex* but I knows what I's likes!  (Not those 2 lines - they need more work).  And any haiku with not exactly 17 syllables could be enjoyable but less than perfect.  Therein lies the challenge! :-)

Comment: @Kristina: But all the best Persian carpets include [a deliberate imperfection](http://gracialouise.typepad.com/high_up_in_the_trees/2009/12/the-imperfection-in-the-persian-rug.html). So perhaps by the time I finally write my 16 1/2 -syllable haiku, you'll be sufficiently enlightened to classify it as "perfect", within its own terms of engagement!

Comment: touché! lol!  It will be entirely lovely - all the more for its very human imperfection!

Comment: I can't add much to what Kristina and FF have said. Merely wanted to mention that the "Writers" StackExchange is the perfect place for this question.

Comment: "Some will watch as you go down quick" has a much better meter.

Comment: Yes, and "Some will watch you go down quick" would be even better.